# What is wrong with my usage of SED in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I am trying to replace some characters in text as follows:

```
cat Input.txt | sed -e "s/Ä…/ą/g" > file1.tmp &&
cat file1.tmp | sed -e "s/Ä„/Ą/g" > file2.tmp &&
cat file2.tmp | sed -e 's/Ä‡/ć/g' > file1.tmp &&
cat file1.tmp | sed -e 's/Ä™/ę/g' > file2.tmp &&
cat file2.tmp | sed -e 's/Å‚/ł/g' > file1.tmp &&
cat file1.tmp | sed -e 's/Å¼/ż/g' > file2.tmp &&
cat file2.tmp | sed -e 's/Ã³/ó/g' > file1.tmp &&
cat file1.tmp | sed -e 's/Å„/ń/g' > file2.tmp &&
cat file2.tmp | sed -e 's/Å›/ś/g' > file1.tmp &&
cat file1.tmp | sed -e 's/Åº/ź/g' > file2.tmp &&
cat file2.tmp | sed -e 's/Ä†/Ć/g' > file1.tmp &&
cat file1.tmp | sed -e 's/Ä˜/Ę/g' > file2.tmp &&
cat file2.tmp | sed -e 's/Å/Ł/g' > file1.tmp &&
cat file1.tmp | sed -e 's/Åƒ/Ń/g' > file2.tmp &&
cat file2.tmp | sed -e 's/Ã“/Ó/g' > file1.tmp &&
cat file1.tmp | sed -e 's/Åš/Ś/g' > file2.tmp &&
cat file2.tmp | sed -e 's/Å¹/Ź/g' > file1.tmp &&
cat file1.tmp | sed -e 's/Å»/Ż/g' > file2.tmp &&
cat file2.tmp | sed -e 's/â€“/,/g' > file1.tmp &&
cat file1.tmp | sed -e 's/â€¢/•/g' > file2.tmp &&
cat file2.tmp | sed -e "s/ &apos;/\'/g" > file1.tmp &&
cat file1.tmp | sed -e 's/ &quot;/"/g' > file2.tmp &&
cat file2.tmp | sed -e 's/ą/a/g' > file1.tmp &&
cat file1.tmp | sed -e 's/ę/e/g' > file2.tmp &&
cat file2.tmp | sed -e 's/ś/s/g' > file1.tmp &&
cat file1.tmp | sed -e 's/ć/c/g' > file2.tmp &&
cat file2.tmp | sed -e 's/ń/n/g' > file1.tmp &&
cat file1.tmp | sed -e 's/ł/l/g' > file2.tmp &&
cat file2.tmp | sed -e 's/ź/z/g' > file1.tmp &&
cat file1.tmp | sed -e 's/ż/z/g' > file2.tmp &&
cat file2.tmp | sed -e 's/ó/o/g' > file1.tmp &&
cat file1.tmp | sed -e 's/Ą/A/g' > file2.tmp &&
cat file2.tmp | sed -e 's/Ę/E/g' > file1.tmp &&
cat file1.tmp | sed -e 's/Ś/S/g' > file2.tmp &&
cat file2.tmp | sed -e 's/Ć/C/g' > file1.tmp &&
cat file1.tmp | sed -e 's/Ń/N/g' > file2.tmp &&
cat file2.tmp | sed -e 's/Ł/L/g' > file1.tmp &&
cat file1.tmp | sed -e 's/Ź/Z/g' > file2.tmp &&
cat file2.tmp | sed -e 's/Ż/Z/g' > file1.tmp &&
cat file1.tmp | sed -e 's/Ó/O/g' > file2.tmp &&
cat file2.tmp | sed -e 's/./ ./g' > file1.tmp &&
cat file1.tmp | sed -e 's/,/ ,/g' > file2.tmp &&
head file2.tmp
```

And I get following error:

File "", line 2
ą(/g", >, file1.tmp, &&)
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

What am I doing wrong ? I tried different quatations and \ before symbols but still no use...

Comment: FYI: You can provide multiple substitutions either by separating them on a newline, a `;` or by using the `-e` flag multiple times: `sed 's/a/b/;s/b/c/;'` `sed -e 's/a/b/' -e 's/b/c/'.

Comment: You shouldn't use the same file as input and output. If you want to update a file in place, use the `-i` option.

Comment: I suspect the error is because `sed` doesn't understand literal multi-byte characters. Use hex escape sequences.

Comment: In fact this used to work in ubuntu 16.04. Now on google colabolatory I face such issue. What is hex escape sequence ??